# How to iterate through date and time text file, line by line?

Tags: arcpy, iteration, datetime

I am building a model on ArcGIS and I am now trying to iterate through a text file that contains in each line date and time information.
I tried to do that on Model Builder, only I used the get field tool but I couldn't figure out how to iterate line per line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a couple of months ago and solved it using the convert time tool to insert the dates and times from a text file into a table. Afterwards I iterated through each row in the table. 
Does this help?
If not, could you give us more details?

Comment: The problem here is that I already have an iterator in my model

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing more details. Could you post a screenshot of the model? I can only think of creating a new model to relate date and times to each feature/raster by FID.

Comment: How can i add a screenshot in a comment? and in my model i'm iterating through shapefiles so that afetrwards i can apply Clip tool for each shp with a polygon. And i want to attach to each clip a particular date and time from my text file.

Comment: It has to be in a new answer, not a comment

Comment: It keeps giving me an error message each time i try to upload the image.

Comment: I think I'll have to add a field to each shapefile (output of the iterator) and fill it with its date and time (from the beginning). So that I can use them after for another tool. But, this task will be very tiresome. isn't there any other solution?

Comment: apparently you can embed one model in another! https://community.esri.com/thread/57519  
Well good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create a second model for the second iterator.  Make sure it has a model parameter that you can use to pass input to it.  Embed the second model into the first one (drag it from the catalog view into the first model's edit window).  Connect to model's parameter.

If necessary, you can also have the second model's output made into a model parameter, and connect it to something else in the first model, to continue processing there.